# Sum of (random) distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, simulation, monte-carlo

I am trying to predict the revenues of a portfolio of items. I want to simulate the revenues in a particular market situation in which they might increase. Each item's revenues is made up of 3 components:

Revenues per item = 
constant * percentage_increase_for_A(item) * A(item) + 
constant * percentage_increase_for_B(item) * B(item) + 
constant * percentage_increase_for_C(item) * C(item)

As you can see, each of the percentage increases depends on the item since each item has a different one depending on item type and region. A, B and C are just the current base values of each item that contribute to revenues.

The percentage increases are extracted from normal distributions. I simulate each item's revenues using a Monte Carlo simulation, where the variable is the percentage increase for an item. So I use a for cycle that fully (until the specified number of simulation is reached) simulates an item before going to the next item (and simulate it). To make sure that items of same type and region are simulated the same way (same "simulation path" for the percentage increases values), I have fixed the seed using Python's numpy seed.

At the end I have something like this:

[image]

I want to know what is the mean, median and some percentiles of the TOTAL revenues of the portfolio of items and obtain a probability distribution for the total revenues.
What I plan to do is summing the revenues of each item at each simulation. So, for example, for simulation 0 I will have \$20,000.00 + \$10,000.00 + \$30,000.00 + \$15,000.00 = \$75,000.00 total revenues for the portfolio of items. Doing this for each simulation, I will have various values of the total revenues and will be able to plot the probability distribution and get various percentiles.

Would this way of summing to get the total revenues probability distribution be correct? I don't think I have to go through convolutions or anything like that in my case, is it correct? Although, I am wondering this: am I summing percentiles by doing this? I know that, for example, the median of the sum is not equal to the sum of the medians. The revenues of each item in a single simulation are not percentiles by themselves but they are if you consider the revenues of one single item at all the simulations. Hence, since I go simulation by simulation when summing, I assume I am not doing anything wrong. Is it correct?

Please note: since the actual problem is a bit different from the one I described here, it might happen that the probability distributions of the revenues of some items don't follow a normal distribution, while others do. Would my approach be still correct then?

Another question is this: from a statistical point of view, can the revenues of each item be considered random variables or is the only actual random variable the percentage increase described above, extracted from a normal distribution?