# Monte Carlo simulations and Central Limit theorem

Tags: random-variable, simulation, monte-carlo, central-limit-theorem

I am simulating the revenues of a portfolio of items using one input variable. This variable is randomly extracted from a normal distribution n times, where n is the number of Monte Carlo simulations. Revenues is the output parameter and they indeed depend on this random variable. 
I know that, in general, as per the Central Limit theorem, the output parameter of a Monte Carlo simulation should have a normal distribution. However, my case is peculiar: although the revenues depend on the randomly extracted variable that is mentioned above, there are cases in which, for particular values of this variable the revenues are just set to 0. This does not mean that they don't depend on the random variable, but just that, for particular values of this one, they are coded to be 0. 
This implies that the distribution of the revenues at the end of the simulations is not normal. In my opinion it makes sense that it is like this, as this is how the model is supposed to work and it reflects reality. In the end, I am using the obtained distributions of revenues to extract statistics of it (mean, median, percentiles,...), regardless of its shape. Does it make sense or are the concepts of "Monte Carlo" and "normal distribution of the output parameter at the end of the simulations" necessarily tied up together?

Comment: "as per the Central Limit theorem, the output parameter of a Monte Carlo simulation should have a normal distribution." --- it's not at all clear that the CLT applies. It's not true of Monte Carlo output in general (though it is sometimes true). If you left out some important condition that would make the CLT relevant (e.g. that you're calculating something akin to an average or a sum, rather than something quite different, such as a maximum or transformed sum), you should include that information in your question. The distribution of revenues will not usually be a linear function of a sum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, each of the items has revenues that depend on that input variable. When that input variable goes below a certain value, the revenues for that item are set to be 0. By doing this, the total revenues (obtained by summing the revenues of all the items at each simulation) will not have a normal distribution in the end. This result is expected and, if I got your answer right, having a normal distribution of the output parameter is not something that always occurs. Is it correct?

Comment: Certainly, having a normal distribution for the output of some Monte Carlo simulation is not always the case. e.g. if I simulate draws from a normal, and exponentiate those draws to get my output, the resulting output is lognormal not normal. If I instead simulate draws from an exponential, subtract 1 and then set everything below 0 to 0, then I have a 0-inflated exponential... and so forth.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: op i think you are confusing what the 'output' of a mc simulation is.often you use the sample mean of the realisations, for which CLT is likely applicable so the sample mean will be approximately normal

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would the sample mean of the realisations be in my case? I described here what I am trying to do in detail: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/615750/sum-of-random-distributions